# What is the time complexity of the algorithm to check if a number is prime?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I need to find what is the time complexity of an algorithm that checks if an integer is prime? This algorithm  is a bit different in that it uses a while loop to accomplish its task

Here's the method in Java:

```
    public static boolean isPrime(int num) {
        int i = 2;
        boolean isPrime = false;

        while(num % i != 0) {
            i += 1;
        }

        if (num == i) {
            isPrime = true;
        }

        return isPrime;
    }
```

For the while loop, I have one comparison and I have one if statement outside the loop, the if statement will always be ran once so O(1). Now what is big-O of the while loop? Is it O(n)?

Comment: Yes, worst case is `O(n)`.

Comment: @VishnuDasu So the whill loop will run n number of times?

Comment: If the number `num` is prime, then yes it will run `num` times which is the worst case.

Comment: A better algorithm only checks against 2, and all the odd numbers up to the square root of n. For example, If you want to know if 101 is prime, you only have to compare against 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, and 11. That algorithm would have complexity O(sqrt(n)).

Answer (score 3):

Your method may have some slight problems (addressed below), but your approach should be `O(n)`, where `n` is the value/size of the input to `isPrime()`.  That is, in this brute force method, you are basically just cycling through every possible value less than the input to find an exact match.

I would rewrite as:

```
// assuming positive integers only
public static boolean isPrime(int num) {
    if (num == 1) return false;

    boolean isPrime = true;

    for (int i=2; i < Math.sqrt(num); ++i) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
            isPrime = false;
            break;
        }

    return isPrime;
}
```

I check if the input be 1, in which case it is not a prime number.  Also, this approach has the added benefit of that it only checks up to `sqrt(num)` for possible divisors.  Any divisor greater than that cannot possibly divide evenly, so there is no point in checking.  If we find a divisor, then we break from the `for` loop.

Comment: Why would this method be better than mine? And why the num / 2 ?

Comment: It would suffice if we iterate till `sqrt(n)`.

Comment: So sqrt(n) is the big O of this algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is `O(N)`. Where N is `num`.